# Area lights not affecting objects #Three.js

Tags: three.js

I found this code by #WestLangley in stackoverflow which creates an arealight over a basic plane. When i tried to use this code and modify for my room model which has objects,floor and wall, it's not casting any light in the scene, the area light works again only when i add a plane below it.

can any one tell me what changes has to be made in the code so that area light falls on objects inside the room, without adding a plane below it ?

codepen.io/Kuranes/pen/klgdJ

Comment: which object?i don't get it

Comment: Snail, By saying objects i mean the chairs and window inside my room model.

Comment: can you show us your code example.?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=saJQjQcwhT
part of the code where i add object and area light to the scene

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8n62u7gb/
sorry about that, please see this.

Comment: that's not a working example.

Comment: Snail, the code is too long , this is just a part of the code where i pull in the area light and place them in the room model.

Comment: please make a minimal code example.all the big code don't need to demonstrate your problem.